# Parse checkbox change value to Model and then to JSON object on button click in VIEW ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.checkbox

Working with a form where user should be able to uncheck pre selected `checkbox` and save that state on `AJAX` post through `JSON` object to the `Controller` in `ASP.Net MVC`

[image]

**Requirement:**

1. Unchecking a pre selected checkbox should change a row in the database property from "Active" = 'Y' to "Active=" = 'N'
2. Newly selected checkbox would create a complete new row in the db

**Problem:**

1. After unchecking the selected text box Model is not updated in `VIEW`. Hence serverside data is not updated. Requires a client side update before data is parsed into `AJAX` call.
2. Don't know how to capture the checkbox value change and pass it to the Model so that parsed data can then be changed to button click/submit form.
3. Following code also gives error 200 because dataType is supposedly incorrect on submit (doing a button submit here).

**View:**

```
@model List<DashboardPermissionTool.ViewModels.UserViewModel>
@using (@Html.BeginForm(new { id = "UserForm" }))
{
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model[0].Roles.Count; i++)
        {
            <th>
                @Model[0].Roles[i].RoleName
            </th>
        }
    </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].UserName)
                @Model[i].UserName
            </td>
            @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Roles.Count; j++)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Roles[j].IsSelected)
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<div class="form-actions">
    <a id="SubmitUserRoles" class="btn btn-success submit" value="Save">Save changes</a>
</div>

<script>

    var parsedData = @Html.Raw( new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#SubmitUserRoles").click(function () {

            $('input[type=checkbox]').on("change",function(){
                if($(this).prop('checked'))
                {
                    $(this).attr('checked', false); 
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).attr('checked', true); 
                }                  
            });

              $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "User")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(parsedData),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

}

**HTML Response:** : For each **selected check box** Response is as follows:

```
<td>
     <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required." name="[0].Roles[0].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
     <input name="[0].Roles[0].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false" />
</td>
```

For each **unchecked check box** Response is as follows:

```
<td>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required." name="[0].Roles[1].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
    <input name="[0].Roles[1].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false" />
</td>
```

**ViewModels:**

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<RoleViewModel> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class RoleViewModel
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; } 
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } 
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(List<UserViewModel> model)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < model[i].Roles.Count; j++)
            {
                db.User.Add(new User
                {
                    username = model[i].UserName,
                    role = model[i].Roles[j].RoleName
                });                  
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
        }
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

Comment: All you need is `data: $('form').serialize()` and remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` and it will all be sent and bound correctly (I'm assuming the model in the view is `List<UserViewModel>`). Although its a bit unclear why you would want to stay in the same page after the user has made the changes

Comment: And you `return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");` and `return View("Index", model);` in the method is pointless - ajax calls do not redirect and your code will throw an exception because you specify the return type is `json` when your actually returning `html`

Comment: You also need to remove the `$('input[type=checkbox]').on("change",function(){ ... }` script (not clear what you think that is trying to do)

Comment: @StephenMuecke all your suggestions just worked like magic.Now I get the correct Response.However, even if I reditrect to another View, it still gives error 200. How should `return View("Index", model);` be handled in the `Controller`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke could you also please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept and this would help others if they are having similar issues.

Comment: You have numerous other errors as well :) But the main thing is why are you using ajax when you appear to want to redirect to another view? Do you really want to stay on the same page?

Comment: It late here and its going to be a very long answer so I'll add it tomorrow :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Using AJAX, only because felt convinient.Needed to be on the same page due to some business requirement.However, I would change that and redirect user to HOME page. Any chance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126559/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sharlene).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

Starting with the controller method, you have a `return` statement inside the outer `for` loop which means that you only ever save the values of the 1st `UserViewModel` and then exit the method. To save all records, it needs to be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<UserViewModel> model)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < model[i].Roles.Count; j++)
        {
            db.User.Add(new User { username = model[i].UserName, role = model[i].Roles[j].RoleName });                  
        }
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
}
```

But its clear from this method, that you want to redirect to the `Index()` method after saving the records, so using ajax to submit the data is pointless (ajax calls stay on the same page and do not redirect) so you should be using a normal submit button to submit the form (and delete all your scripts). You need to change

```
<a id="SubmitUserRoles" class="btn btn-success submit" value="Save">Save changes</a>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit" value="Save" />
```

and note also that `value` is not a valid attribute for an `<a>` element.

But to address the other issues with your code, lets assume you do want to stay on the same page and update the DOM.

First

```
var parsedData = @Html.Raw( new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
```

(and your can simply use `var parsedData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` instead) is serializing the original model, so you just posting back the original values, not the edited values. In order to pass the edited values, you ajax option needs to be

```
data: $('form').serialize(),
```

Next

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

means you send the data as json, but you have not stringified the data. It would need to be

```
data: JSON.stringify($('form').serialize()),
```

in order to bind, but that is unnecessary and you would just need to remove the `contentType` option so that it uses the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`

Next

```
dataType: 'json',
```

means that your specifying that the method return json, but in fact it is returning html so it would throw an exception. It would need to be `dataType: 'html',` or simply remove the option and the ajax method will work it out.

You also need to delete your `$("#SubmitUserRoles").click(function () { ... }` script. The presence of the `checked` attribute means its selected and `checked="checked"` or `checked="true"` or `check="false"` or `checked="anything"` all mean exactly the same thing - that the checkbox is selected. Fortunately that code is never executed (if it did, it would screw everything up) because you only add the handler inside the handler for `$("#SubmitUserRoles").click(function () {` which throws an exception.

Finally

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm(new { id = "UserForm" }))
```

is adding a route value for `id` (if you look at the html your generating, you will see `action="../Create/UserForm"` (or `action="../Create?id=UserForm"` depending on your routes (and your method does not have a parameter `string id`). I assume you think its adding an `id` attribute to the `<form>` tag, in which case you need to use one of the [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Object%29) of `BeginForm()` that accept `htmlAttributes`. However, its only necessary to add an `id` attribute for use with css or javascript selectors, so you can just use

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
```